# Parse - Retrieve only items with matching ACL

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, acl, parse-cloud-code

Sorry if my title isn't really what I'm after, had a hard time thinking of a good one.

I'm fairly (very) new to Parse and here's my (probably quite easy) question:

I've got two users: "Test_user_1" and "Test_user_2".
I've created an instance (object) of the class "Progression" and also set the ACL using ".setACL(new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()));" when creating the object (on the cloud-code), while being logged in with Test_user_1. Meaning only Test_user_1 should have access to this right?

I then want to query for the object "Progression" but only want to retrieve the Progression associated with the currently logged in user. So in my scenario above. If Test_user_1 queries for "Progression" I want him to receive one instance (the one "he" created). While Test_user_2 should receive zero.

Is there some standard way to achieve this using only ACL and current user? Or do I need to save the userId (of the user) field in the Progression-class and query by this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're logged in as User 1 the query *should* only fetch objects, this user has access to. There shouldn't be any additional setup required by you (except setting up the ACL properly ;))

So simply login as User 1, build your query and run it.

Comment: Ahh thank you for the quick answer! I will try this right away (I feel kinda stupid not trying it out, but couldn't find it in the docs!)